# How does one reconcile Nietzsche's view of kindness?

Tags: ethics, nietzsche, metaethics

On the  one hand, N espouses that people shall almost ignore the needs of other people to achieve one's own greatness. But on the other hand he describes kindness as

"Kindness and love, the most curative herbs and agents in human intercourse".

Comment: Can one?  It's far from the only flat-out contradiction in his corpus.

Comment: Do you have quote/s on him ignoring the needs of others? His mental breakdown was precipitated apparently by seeing a horse beaten in the street.

Comment: There is no contradiction. Empathy makes kindness a non zero sum game: watch happy people tends to make us happy, all the more if they're happy because of us. Great leaders tend to be able of sincere care to the people they lead, which is a key factor in inspiring them and achieve greatness. Nobody likes to follow a mean individual who will drop them at the first occasion. For an example see the depiction of Nelson Mandela and his effect on the character of Francois Pienaar in the movie [Invictus](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1057500/).

Comment: (cont.) For a counter example, the last few months of US politics... What Nietzsche dismisses about kindness (in a very vague nutshell, corrections welcome) is the *moral injunction* to show kindness, all too often in his view the way for mediocre people to tame a great person: "this great painter neglects wife and kids to pursue his creation, shame on him!". For Nietzsche this should not stop the great artist in his path, nor should he affect to show kindness to please the crowd. But if kindness is coming from the bottom of his heart, if he trully desires to be kind, it's all for the better.

Comment: As far as I know Nietzsche says nothing about ignoring the needs of others.  I’m interested in seeing a source on that as well.

Comment: The full quote: "Economy of kindness. Kindness and love, the most curative herbs and agents in human intercourse, are such precious finds that one would hope these balsamlike remedies would be used as economically as possible; but this is impossible. Only the boldest Utopians would dream of the economy of kindness."

Answer (score 1):

I can hardly back the following up with quotes  as it is what I heard from scholars in Nietzsche's own house and the Nietzsche Archive in Weimar:

Basically, we should be somewhat careful when it comes to the interpretation of some of his works. His sister, Elisabeth, was a devoted anti-semitic woman who was part of the intellectual circles that developed an early version of what later became Nazi ideology. She wholly embraced and actively furthered the (mis!)use of Nietzsche as kind of a Nazi forethinker when he fell ill. There are good arguments to be made that this is something he would have strongly opposed would he still have had his strength and wits together, one of them being that there are notes on how much he despised his sister and her friends for their ways of thinking. In order to make Nietzsche's works fit with that ideology, she even heavily edited and selectively promoted certain passages and works of him, something that only slowly is discovered through the sighting and digitalisation of all of his manuscripts. The research on that is still ongoing, though.

In that light, I would like to suggest that the whole Übermensch and "master morality" is not to be interpreted as the rightful rule of the (politically and physically) powerful over the weak as those people wanted us to believe, but rather as the moral self-empowerment of the strong-willed as opposed to those relying on external guidance on what is right and wrong. Mastery not over others, but one's own principles and actions.

That, in turn, does by no means have to mean we end up with people who recklessly walk over corpses for their goals. What we see in these texts is how Nietzsche sought how to think *actual moral autonomy*, something that Kant fell well short of in his eyes because of an essentially divine Categorical Imperative ([see this paper for a similar line of thought](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/phpr.12824)). Quite similar to contemporary ideas of empowerment and authenticity and nothing less than avantgarde existentialism.

Taking it that way, we can see how love and compassion can be seen as not only not in conflict, but rather complementary to his views on moral autonomy: It is, so to speak, the inner compass and what builds good character, without which his 'master morality' without a doubt would - and did - lead to horrendous outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, when you refer to his espousal of the idea that one must *ignore the needs of other people to achieve one's own greatness*, that you're referring to Nietzsche's ideas of *slave* and *master morality*, in particular the latter "virtue". I believe this to be an instance of the conflicting nature of philosophy and reality which yields reality paramount, solely for the sake of one's psyche.

It might be argued that Nietzsche suffered existentially his entire philosophical career; yet, such suffering was visible especially physically during the few years preceding his demise. As is summarized by many texts on the causes of and conditions around Nietzsche's passing, he suffered a "long sickness" - a period of utter desperation, pain, and melancholy. Nietzsche had, in some ways, *reasoned* himself into his depressive state, a result of his hyper-rational philosophy, including that which you claim is his espousal of self-centered gain. It was during such periods of sickness that Nietzsche "yearned for the emotional solace" that values such as kindness - and others that he believe constituted *slave morality* - offered. In short, the way of reconciling these ideas is to understand that one - motivation by sole egocentric gain - led to the other - existential suffering and the realization of the importance of communal values.

Comment: Direct quotes & references would improve this answer.

Comment: Is there any evidence that Nietzsche actually advocated the master morality for modern people (according to [this article](https://bigthink.com/scotty-hendricks/the-master-and-slave-moralities-what-nietzsche-really-meant), Nietzsche scholar Walter Kaufman denied that he did), or was his defense of master morality more about saying that it worked well for the ancient classical world, and that it was undermined by the slave morality? It may be that he thought in the modern world we need a new ethos which is different from either one.

Answer (score 0):

Nietzsche doesn't present a positive and systematic philosophy, much of what he offers are observations.

Now, when we ask someone for directions and they observe to go from A to B, you need to go through D. And then later, when you ask him again, he says, go through M and this without even acknowledging he had first said D, most people would say don't trust his observations on directions: he is apt to say anything. But of course, one could counter that philosophy is not like finding directions. The latter has bern solved - just use a map. Whilst the former is an ongoing project and it is so because it is very difficult terrain. And so, the best that the best can do, is offer only observations. This is an adequate explanation, but doesn't go far enough. Philosophy, to be anything, needs to be systematic: distances have to be measured, goals established and flagposts put up. His commentators acknowledge this, but much of what is offered misses out on the difficult Nietzsche: for example, the Nietzsche that prescribed death to the 'weak' and 'failures' as the very heart of his 'love of man'.

The full quote is an aphorism in *Human, All too Human*.

> Kindness and love, the most curative herbs and agents in human intercourse are such precious finds that one would hope that these balsamlike remedies would be used as economically as possible. But this is impossible, only the most boldest of utopians would dream of the economy of kindness.

Yet, he goes ahead does precisely that:

> Amongst the small and endlessly abundant and therefore very effective things that science ought to heed more than the great, rare things, is goodwill. I mean those expressions of a friendly disposition in interactions, that smile of the eye, those handclasps, that ease which usually envelops nearly all human actions.

> Every teacher, every official brings this ingredient to what he considers his duty. It is the continual manifestation of our humanity, its rays of light, so to speak in which everything grows. Especially within the narrowest circle, the family, life sprouts and blossoms only by this goodwill.

> Good nature, friendliness, and courtesy of the heart are ever-flowing tributaries of that selfless drive and have much made much greater contributions to culture than those more famous expressions of this drive, called pity, charity and self-sacrifice. But we tend to under-estimate them and in fact there is not much about them that is selfless. The sum of these small doses is nevertheless, mighty. It's cumulative force is amongst the strongest of forces.

> Similarly, there is much more happiness to be found in the world than dim eyes can see, if one calculates correctly, and does not forget all those moments of ease which are so plentiful in human life, even amongst the most oppressed.

According to Freud, "he had a more penetrating understanding of himself than any other man who had ever lived". Yet, there is precious little evidence of this self-awareness here. Here, we see him descending from the heights of his ubermensch 'master morality' of an elite to examine the 'slave morality' of the majority. And he is forced to see beyond his own 'dim eyes' that ordinary human courtesy and kindness adds up to a great deal, to one of the greatest forces known to man. Yet he writes as though he wasn't the exponent of 'master morality' and never had been, even though, this is what he is best known for. His own first 'calculation' was badly thought through, and here we see him trying to make amends. But to make amends properly, one needs to acknowledge ones mistakes, and hell will freeze over first before Nietszche will push himself to that. Of course, this is another reason why Nietzche is full of inconsistencies.

Martin Ruehl, a scholar of German intellectual history at Cambridge university [says](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/long_reads/nietzsche-ideas-superman-slavery-nihilism-adolf-hitler-nazi-racism-white-supremacy-fascism-a8138396.html?amp):

> Almost without exception, Nietzsche scholars have either ignored his pro-slavery comments or urged them to read them metaphorically. Political theorists eager to claim him as a champion of radical democracy have tip-toed aroumd them ... [He is] the only modern philosopher to fundamebtally reject the credo of modernity, namely all are created equal and have an inalienable right to liberty.

He also says:

> Praising him as a champion of (self)-liberation they ignore the severe restrictions he places on the idea of human liberation.

His thoughts on master-slave morality were not simply thoughts in absracto, he applied them to one of the great debates of the day:

> In a topical entry in 1884 [from his *nachlass*], he condemns tge emancipatory movements transforming Western societies in the 19th C. Nietsche lists their objects with palpable disdain: women, slaves, workers, "the sick, the corrupt". The fragment leaves little doubt that its author considers tge emancipation of these groups a disastrous mistake bound to exacerbate the "levelling of the European male" and the decay of contemporary European culture

Answer (score -1):

One of the more difficult things with Nietzsche is understanding the difference between what he *observes* and what he *advocates*. Nietzsche had a keen eye for (what we would now call) social-psychological detail, but he had an almost poetic or romantic (in the sense of [romanticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanticism)) form of expression. His style doesn't fit well with the rational/analytical mode that we normally expect from philosophy, but it doesn't dissolve into advocacy or punditry either, so it takes some work to get at his intentions.

In this particular case, the confusion lies around his investigation of the Master and Slave moralities. Nietzsche *describes* these two moral paradigms in intimate (and somewhat gaudy) detail, but my sense is that he's simply observing them as they exist in the world. He's not evaluating them, and not (as such) asking his readers to evaluate them either. For Nietzsche, these paradigms are things to be seen, understood, and then transcended. It isn't quite a dialectical synthesis; in fact, it may be closer to Adorno's later conception of a negative dialectic. The goal is to rid oneself of *both* moral paradigms and reach something truer and more vital.

Of course, most people aren't capable of removing themselves from the moral paradigms they are enmeshed by, and those who are inclined to read Nietzsche in the first place are going to find the Master morality more intuitively appealing, warts and all. They might decry the harshness of it, but they would be averse to polluting the purity of it with elements of the slave morality (which would be the normal approach in, say, Hegelian synthesis). But Nietzsche is really saying something like: "There are things we value *here* (like determinate will); there are things we value *there* (like kindness and grace); there are things in both we dislike, but retain for the sake of the things we value." He outlines a set of psychological knots and constraints that bind us as we are brought into one or the other of these moral paradigms, but merely dangles the idea that we don't need to be bound that way.

Put another way, what you're seeing is not a contradiction in Nietzsche. You're seeing is a paradox in the conventional moral universe: someone who appears to mix Master and Slave morality. Step outside the conventional moral universe, however, and the paradox disappears.